# Initializing C array without stange chars?

Tags: c, arrays, syntax, char

(I already know other languages but this exam I'm preparing require to know C which I never really looked into before.)

`EDIT : WOAH SO MANY ANSWERS... Give me a few mins to read all of them, thank you so much !`

Here is my code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char search_for[80]; // <----- I think the problem is either here
    printf("Search for : ? \n");
    fgets(search_for, 80, stdin); // <---- or here
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
        printf("Char i : %c - %p \n", search_for[i], &search_for[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output, see those weird chars in the end ? Why are they here ?

```
Search for : ? 
New
Char i : N - 0x7fff52eb4ba0 
Char i : e - 0x7fff52eb4ba1 
Char i : w - 0x7fff52eb4ba2 
Char i : 
 - 0x7fff52eb4ba3 
Char i : � - 0x7fff52eb4ba4 
Char i : � - 0x7fff52eb4ba5 
Char i : � - 0x7fff52eb4ba6 
Char i : � - 0x7fff52eb4ba7 
Char i : 
 - 0x7fff52eb4ba8 
Char i : � - 0x7fff52eb4ba9 
Char i : � - 0x7fff52eb4baa 
Char i : � - 0x7fff52eb4bab 
Char i :  - 0x7fff52eb4bac 
Char i : � - 0x7fff52eb4bad 
Char i : � - 0x7fff52eb4bae 
Char i : � - 0x7fff52eb4baf 
Char i : @ - 0x7fff52eb4bb0 <---- ??
Char i : ∑ - 0x7fff52eb4bb1 <---- ??
Char i : î - 0x7fff52eb4bb2 <---- ??
Char i : l - 0x7fff52eb4bb3 <---- ??
Char i : ˇ - 0x7fff52eb4bb4 <---- ??
```

... and other lines with weird chars ..

Comment: what is weird with them?

Comment: Well they shouldn't be here ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are there because `search_for` is not initialised:

```
char search_for[80]; /* Will contain random characters. */
```

and `fgets()` will not necessarily write to every element in the buffer.

The `for` loop though accesses every element in `search_for`. To not examine the unitialised elements of `search_for` use `search_for[i]` instead of `i < 80` as the terminating condition:

```
for (int i = 0; search_for[i]; i++)
```

This loop will then terminate when the null terminating character is encountered in `search_for`, which [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) always writes (and does not write anything after, hence the junk characters):

> Reads at most count - 1 characters from the given file stream and stores them in str. **The produced character string is always NULL-terminated.** Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that newline character.

Comment: Great thanks ! english isn't my native language, how could I "initialize the buffer" ?

Comment: Thanks I didn't know I could do that !

Comment: what would happen if I input 81 non null chars ?

Comment: I think fget doesn't record more than the limit you set (here 80)

Comment: @Oren, `fgets()` reads one less than the supplied argument leaving room for the terminating null character.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop should print only for the length of the string. Hence, the loop should be `for (i = 0; i < strlen(search_for); i++)`.

Beyond the string length, since your array is uninitialized, the previous contents of the stack are printed which get reflected as special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Weird chars appears because `fgets` sets only your 3 chars of `"New"` string + `1 nul` char.... the other `76 chars` are not set thus thet may contains random values.

If you wanna be sure they're zeroed, use `bzero(search_for, 80)` just after the declaration
or just loop for the `strlen` of the `search_for` buffer instead of loop for all the 80 chars

Answer (score 1):

you are printing whatever was in the memory location assigned by `char search_for[80]` before that was beyond the length of your input. you should initialize (clean) `search_for` array.

you do that like `char search_for[80] ={ 0 }; // initialize all 80 chars to zero`

Answer (score 1):

Because you did not properly initialize your char array search_for, you are just getting random characters.

When you type an input string starting with "New", you have also typed new line character '\n' after that word and your array initialization ended there.

You can get your real character number by strlen(search_for)